# Show Custom Post Type meta boxes only on Page Edit

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, metabox, post-meta, page-template

I've went through the laborious process of creating the CPT. I see it on the sidebar of my WP install, I can add new, save data, and on frontend I can output the data. Is it possible with WP to move the CPT meta boxes into a Page Edit? I know I see the default 'Custom Fields' with the dropdown that shows the CPT values, but this is very bad UX. I'd like the post meta box to just show up only on the Page Edit for a specific template. I am curious how I would approach this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your problem is not clear. Are you asking that your custom metaboxes should only be visible in backend on some page templates??

Comment: i want to be able to show the CPT meta boxes only on Page edit

Comment: The meta boxes you created are for custom post type. They are going to appear in custom post edit(when you add new / edit your custom post type). Those meta boxes are not going to appear for pages(which is also a type of post type). So if also want the same metaboxes to appear for pages also you will have to add the code for post type pages also

Comment: Or may be i didn't understand the problem

Comment: i would love to know what the code is for "..add the code for post type pages also"

Comment: what code you have used so far to add meta boxes to custom post type .Update your question with that code , then i can give you the code accordingly